# Kafka Connect when we have multiple queries

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

How can we use Kafka Connect when there are multiple tables to be inserted?

I am trying to implement Kafka connect sink to insert to multiple Oracle table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either define one [JDBC Sink Connector](http://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/index.html) per table, or a single [JDBC Sink Connector](http://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/index.html) with multiple `topics` specified - each topic will be written to a separate table. The table will take the topic name, which you can also map using the [`table.name.format`](http://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/sink_config_options.html#data-mapping) option.